# Unable tp open browser with specified URL in leanFT

Tags: java, leanft

Error is specified below while performing the action.

Picked up `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`: `-agentlib:jvmhook`

Picked up `_JAVA_OPTIONS`: `-Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\LeanFT\bin\java_shared\classes";"C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\LeanFT\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"`

```
public class LeanFtTest {

     @Before
        public void init(){
            try {
                ModifiableSDKConfiguration config = new ModifiableSDKConfiguration();
                config.setServerAddress(new URI("ws://localhost:5095"));
                SDK.init(config);
            }catch (Exception ex){
                System.out.println("Exception occured " + ex.toString());
            }
        }

    @Test
    public void test() throws GeneralLeanFtException {

        Browser browser = BrowserFactory.launch(BrowserType.CHROME);
        try {
            browser.navigate("https://www.google.co.in/");
            browser.sync();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error in navigation");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to edit your question with the full error from log

Comment: Only I'm getting below error in console.
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\LeanFT\bin\java_shared\classes";"C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\LeanFT\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"

Comment: That is not an error. That's just a notification. You need to debug some more. Sounds like those lines are never executed.

Comment: This issue is solved...I added the LeanFT extension to the browser now the code is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see a balloon on the taskbar saying the Leanft runtime has started? If not, then check that part of your code.

If leanft started, did you see a browser start? If not, check that part of your code.

Comment: I'm able to see "LeanFt runtime engine is started" in notification section.. Browser is getting started but not putting the URL in the in browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is a picocomposition.message type not present issue coming while trying to launch the browser from leanft.
Also leanftruntimeengine does not run and broswer does not start.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).